# Black screen on boot with thinkpad yoga 14 and ubuntu/windows 8.1 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 on my new thinkpad yoga 14.

The installation seems ok I can choose windows when GRUB starts and it works. But if I choose ubuntu I get a black screen and have to hard reboot my laptop.

I tried to add nomodeset in the settings of ubuntu in GRUB and it starts and work well. However if I don't write this it won't start

I would like to find why it won't start in quiet splash mode.

I tought it was because of the nvidia geforce 840M graphic card so I tried to install nvidia proprietary drivers but I couldn't  log into the graphic ubuntu and I had to uninstall them using the terminal.

I'm a pretty new user and I don't know what else it could be. I searched but topics on thinkpad yoga are rare and I didn't find other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Ubuntu boots successfully but cannot display anything. The reason is that you have a new graphic card that partially supported in Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 14.04 supports nvidia 331 drivers by default while your card was first supported on nvidia 337+ drivers.

Therefore, you have two options for fixing it: Installing Ubuntu 14.10 (Note: it's not LTS!) or trying to install newer drivers.

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-349 nvidia-settings`

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried to install proprietary nvidia drivers I installed the nvidia-349 and it was impossible to login.

I'm not sure if the system boots correctly because when I press the power button once it doesn't shut down I have to press it for 3-4 second to turn it off. If the system booted normally but didn't display anything it would turn off when I press once like it does when I boot with nomodeset.

Comment: Are you sure? The default configuration for shutdown button in ubuntu is "to ask you which action you want?: (suspend, shutdown, logout etc) and not just shutting it down. What do you mean by saying "impossible to login"?

Comment: I arrived to the login screen and when I entered the pass word I heard the sound of ubuntu and it stayed to the login screen. (And the password was right because when I tried to enter a wrong password it detected it)

Comment: Ok I tried to reinstall 349 drivers and in fact ubuntu still make a black screen if I don't put nomodeset and if I do put nomodeset it boots and when I arrived to the login screen I can't log. Maybe it's not a driver problem? I would really like to stay on ubuntu 14.04 if I can.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved my problem by installing ubuntu 15.04. I still don't know where the problem came from but on a Thinkpad Yoga 14 with nvidia 840M graphic card, ubuntu 15.04 seems to work fine.